# Gmail SMTP Daily user sending quota exceeded

Tags: smtp, gmail

I'm using my gmail account as email-smtp  server.
Today I recieved error message as
"Daily user sending quota exceeded"
How do I check my gmail smtp's max daily sending limit?
Also How do I check my gmail account is trial version or not?

Answer (score 1):

> Also How do I check my gmail account is trial version or not?

Do you pay for your mail account? If so then it is not a trial account.

> How do I check my gmail smtp's max daily sending limit?

There are several limits which can trigger this - a limit for [max messages per](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852) day and certain [size quotas](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en).
And if you mean how you can find out whether you already reached your limit then do count your mails in your inbox...